# how to store values from database to matrix?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here I have a goolemap project.It has a button ..and the activity of the button is: GiveDistance ..

This button should give me the distance between all passed points stored in database.and in order to find distance between them I saved them in a matrix. The question is how to get the value from each row and save in a matrix.

```
public class GiveDistance extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_give_distance);




        double [][] matrix = new double[100][100];

                matrix[0][0]=0;
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                GPSDatabase myDatabase=new GPSDatabase(this);
                myDatabase.open();
                Cursor cursor=myDatabase.getAllRows();
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int i ;
                for ( i = 1; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                       for (int j = 1; j < cursor.getCount(); j++) {
                    matrix[i][j]=9999;
                cursor.moveToNext();

                       }
                          }



                //fill lat and long from database
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    i = 0 ;
                    for (int j = 1; j < cursor.getCount(); j++) {
                //here column 1 includes latitude and column 2 includes logitude

                    matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i]=cursor.getInt(1);//1
                    matrix[i][j]=matrix[j][i]=cursor.getInt(2);//1


                        //String label = cursor.getString(0);

                        cursor.moveToNext();


        //how to get lat and long. from database and save them in matrix[i][j]?
                        //We want them separate!!!!

                    }

                    cursor.close();    


                    //to calc. distance
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int k=0 ;int m,j; 
                    for (j = 1, m =1; j < cursor.getCount(); j++) {

                    for ( i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); m++) {

                    distance(matrix[i][j],matrix[m][k]);

                    }         
                    }
```

Comment: i don't understand what is the quesiton. what error do you face and what does not work ?

Comment: here is the question:             matrix[i][j]=cursor.getInt(1);
how to return the value from the table in cross of column,and row(lattitude)and another sossing in the same row from column longitude and put the 2 values in the matrix[i][j] ...1-Is it true to write getint?2-is it true to put (1) in column index?3-What's the best way to do this?Thanks

Comment: getInt works if your data is an int. 1 works if it is the index of your column. i don't get the third question

Comment: I've 3 columns ..and I want to get 2 values from 2 cells at the same time to save in the matrix element..How can I know the column index?

Comment: read the documentation ?

Comment: why, cursor documentation. what else ?